# Using Azure CLI, Is there a way to find the resource group a resource belongs to?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli

I need this to write a bash script. I have a bunch of resource IDs and I need to find the resource groups to which they belong. Is there someway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The RG name is included in the ID.  The fully qualified ID of the resource, including the resource name and resource type. Use the format, `/subscriptions/{guid}/resourceGroups/{resource-group-name}/{resource-provider-namespace}/{resource-type}/{resource-name}`  Part of the resource ID is the resource group name.

Answer (score 0):

Use az resoure show, to get the values of each resource

```
az resource show --ids /subscriptions/0b1f6471-1bf0-4dda-aec3-111111111111/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MyWebapp
```

If you have many ids, you could write a for loop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a query you could do JMESPath like this:

```
az resource list --query [?id=='the-id'].resourceGroup
```

Or with az resource show --ids

```
az resource show --ids "the-id" --query properties.actionGroups.groupIds
```

You still have to loop through the ids though